# Is there any formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n k!$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Do we have any formula for the sum of factorials above?

Comment: There's no *nice* formula, but there is the [formula given here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html) using the $Ei$ and $E_n$ functions

Comment: You can find more info on this sequence here → https://oeis.org/A003422 but I guess you will be disappointed (I will post one to grab some points, though, because I'm that shallow).

Comment: Nice, quick find, @Omnomnomnom !

Answer (score 2):

According to [its OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A003422), we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k! = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^n - 1}{x - 1}\, e^{-x}\, dx.$$

(I know it's probably not the kind of formulae you're after, but there is not a fundamentally better answer.)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a closed 'closed' form, but:

$$\sum_{k=a}^nk!=-(-1)^a\Gamma(a+1)\cdot!(-a-1)-(-1)^n\Gamma(n+2)\cdot!(-n-2)$$

Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function and $!n$ is the subfactorial function.